# Unable to use authentication mechanisms in db.createUser()

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB 4.2. I tried to test out how to use all the Authentication Mechanisms in mongodb. I did something like this

```
db.createUser({user:"admin2", pwd: "admin2", roles : [{role:"readWrite", db: "test"}], mechanisms : ["SCRAM-SHA-256"]})
```

This worked fine for SCRAM-SHA-1 and SCRAM-SHA-256. But I tried to work with PLAIN, GSSAPI, MONGODB-X509, MONGODB-CR. Like this,

```
db.createUser({user:"admin2", pwd: "admin2", roles : [{role:"readWrite", db: "test"}], mechanisms : ["PLAIN"]})
```

and respectively others. But this does not work throwing an error

```
uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: Unknown auth mechanism 'PLAIN'
```

What is the reason for this issue ? How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Only scram mechanisms are valid in createUser, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/).

For other mechanisms, you need to create a user in the special `$external` database. [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/#procedures) is an example invocation that does that for X.509.

```
db.getSiblingDB("$external").runCommand(
  {
    createUser: "C=US,ST=New York,L=New York City,O=MongoDB,OU=x509,CN=localhost",
    roles: [
         { role: "root", db: "admin" },
    ],
    writeConcern: { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 },
  }
)
```